# How to get Pypi package Info from AWS Codeartifact

Tags: pip, pypi, aws-codeartifact

I have a requirement to get package details without actually installing it, for this thing we have a JSON API in [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/), but in AWS Codeartifact I didn't find any such thing.

In the Pypi JSON API we can just look at the specific paths for package details, for example, to get the info of requests, we can look into https://pypi.org/pypi/requests/json

How to get the package details from the AWS Codeartifact PyPI repo, without actually installing it?

Answer (score 0):

As stated it the [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/python-compatibility.html), AWS CodeArtifact does not support PyPI's JSON API.

Some alternatives are:

- Using `aws` cli to [get package information](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/describe-package-version.html). E.g:
- Using CodeArtifact `DescribePackage` [API action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/APIReference/API_DescribePackage.html)
- Using boto3 client and [`describe_package`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/codeartifact/client/describe_package.html)